# Date or system variable wrongly specified in check constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, date, constraints

```
Alter table tblstaff modify jdate date check ( jdate < sysdate );
```

I have error that

```
ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in check constraint
```

Comment: A constraint is an invariant, it should always be true.  In other words, a row that was allowed today should be allowed tomorrow. Involving sysdate would allow you to construct constraints that are temporal in nature, so that this does not hold true. As such, sysdate and similar functions are disallowed in constraints. Instead you can write triggers that doesn't have this invariant rule, they are just checked when rows are inserted or updated, but the data might become invalid at a later time.

Comment: And yes, I know that your particular rule does not have this problem, unless time starts to flow backwards, but the functions are disallowed nonetheless.

Comment: "_A retrospectively deterministic <boolean value expression> has the property that if it is True at one point time, then it is True for all later points in time if re-evaluated for the identical SQL-data_"

Answer (score 1):

As commented, check constraint won't work but trigger would. Here's an example, adjust it as you wish.

```
create or replace trigger trg_staff_date
  before insert or update on tblstaff
  for each row
begin
  if :new.jdate < sysdate then
     raise_application_error(-20000, 'You can not insert future dates');
  end if;
end;
/
```